# parsing a json-string in classic-asp

Tags: asp.net, json, regex

I have a string like this here:

```
{
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "response":{
        "offset":0,
        "max":50,
        "count":1,
        "locations":[
            {
                "identifier":"0022",
                "id":322433,
                "dateCreated":"2015-10-29T11:26:29.000+01:00",
                "lastUpdated":"2017-02-13T06:22:35.000+01:00",
                "name":"Something something",
                "street":"Some street",
                "streetNo":"3",
                "streetAndNumber":"some text 3",
                "addressExtra":null,
                "zip":"12345",
                "city":"foobar",
                "cellphone":null,
                "fax": null",
                "website":null,
                "email":null,
                "descriptionShort":"desc",
                "descriptionLong":"desc2",
                "openingHoursNotes":"desc3",
                "lastSyncStarted":"2016-09-12T11:14:24.000+02:00",
                "country":"DE",
                "lat":49.000,
                "lng":8.0000,
                "imprint":null,
                "addressDisplay":null,
                "autoSync":null,
                "phone":"null,
                "status":"ACTIVE",
                "keywords":[
                    "some keywords"
                ],
                "categories":[
                    534
                ],
                "locationSyncable":false,
                "businessId":11111,
                "socialPostId":null,
                "hasFacebook":false,
                "endDate":"2017-02-28T00:00:00.000+01:00",
                "openingHours":[
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":1,
                        "from1":"07:00",
                        "to1":"17:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":2,
                        "from1":"07:00",
                        "to1":"17:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":3,
                        "from1":"07:00",
                        "to1":"17:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":4,
                        "from1":"07:00",
                        "to1":"17:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":5,
                        "from1":"07:00",
                        "to1":"17:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "dayOfWeek":6,
                        "from1":"07:30",
                        "to1":"12:00"
                    }
                ],
                "openNow":true,
                "activeDirectoriesCount":45,
                "activeListingsCount":33,
                "publishedListingsCount":45,
                "profileCompleteness":100,
                "missingMandatoryFields":[

                ],
                "visibilityIndex":559,
                "dataPoints":0,
                "province":"Germany"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have to retrieve the value of the 1st occurente of `id` - in that case above it should return `322433`.

Why am I saying it like this? Because I thought about using a `substr` (or something like this) or a `regexp` to obtain the value I need, and a lookup for `id:"` ends in multiple occurences - also it wouldn't be clean and just a messy workaround.

So, I know there are several related questions and I been through all of them, but I'm totally new to classic asp. Coming from PHP and beeing spoiled with a JSON-parser built-in, I'm kinda lost here.

I found a class on git, which should take care of that, but I can't get it running.

See this [here](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON). I tried the exact same thing. Saved the file, included it like my other files and tried to create a new Class, but it ended in a `class not defined` error.

Maybe this is even way too over? I really just need this once. No dynamic generated output or so. This is always coming as a response from a `curl`-request and I simply need to get this specific `id`. Performance plays a kinda relevant role and I guess, using a whole class for that purpose would overdo it.

I tried this `VScript` as well, but I was kinda lost here, as mentioned above.

To provide all of my code, I'll show you the function where I am stuck right now:

```vb
function determineLocationId(identifier)    

    Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    Dim privateKey
    privateKey = "very secret"

    IdentifyUrl = "someUrl"
    With http
      Call .Open("GET", IdentifyUrl, false)
      Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
      Call .SetRequestHeader("CharSet", "utf-8")
      Call .Send()
    End With
    If Left(http.Status, 1) = 2 Then
      response.write("updated")
    Else
      'Output error
      Call Response.Write("Server returned: " & http.Status & " " & http.StatusText)
    End If

    response.write(http.responseText) 'this outputs the json from above
    response.end()

    determineLocationId = identifier
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim str, parser, match, id

str = http.responseText

Set parser = New Regexp
With parser
    .Pattern = """id"":(\d+)"
    .Global = False
End With

Set match = parser.Execute(str)
id = match(0).SubMatches(0)

response.write(id)
```